# Approximation to $\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)dx$ using only $f(0)$, $f'(-1)$, and $f''(1)$

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, quadrature

The exercise is

> Using only $f(0)$, $f'(-1)$, and $f''(1)$, compute an approximation to
>   $\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)dx$ that is exact for all quadratic polynomials

I have only seen guassian quadrature without derivatives so i'm not sure how to go about this. Usually I check what conditions are needed so my approxiation is exact for all monomials of degree $\leq 4$, but since it asks to use derviatives of the function i'm not sure what to do.'

Could anyone lend a hand?

Comment: I suggest using integration by parts formula

Comment: @YuriyS I'm not sure how that would help.

Comment: take $u=f$ and $v=x$, then you get first derivative under the integral, which is a linear function for a quadratic polynomial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**
If $f(x) = ax^2 +bx+c$, you have
$$
\int_{-1}^1 f(x) dx = \frac{2a}{3} + 2c,
$$
can you compute $f(0)$ and $f''(1)$ and complete the problem?

Comment: This way is more simple than what I suggested

Comment: So $\frac{2a}{3} + 2c$ is supposed to be equal to $f(0) + f'(-1) + f''(1)$ ? Er, no that can't be it since I would get $\frac{2a}{3} + 2c = c+b$ which doesn't make sense.

Comment: I see $f(0) = c, f'(-1) = b-2a$ and $f''(1) = 2a$ so the most blatant thing that comes to mind is $$\int_{-1}^1 f(x) dx = \frac{f''(1)}{3} + 2f(0).$$

Comment: oh wow. So then we didn't need $f'(-1)$ at all for our approximation

Comment: @Renon I guess, not